# Control-m batch job is spanning mutliple versions of a singleton ActiveEx server

Tags: control-m

as part of a batch job I create 4 command lines through control-m which invoke a legacy console application written in VB6. The console application invokes an ActiveEx server which performs a set of analytic jobs calculating outputs. The ActiveEx server was coded as a singleton but when invoked through control-m I get 4 instances running. the ActiveEx server does not tear down once the job has completed and the command line has closed it self.

I created 4 .bat files which once launced manually on the server, simulate the calls made through control-m and the ActiveEx server behaves as expected, i.e. there is only 1 instance ever running and once complete it closes down gracefully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Control-M jobs are run under a service account and it same as we login as a user and execute a job. How did you test this? Did you manually executed each batch job one after another or you have executed all the batch job at the same time from different terminals? You can do one thing. Run the control-M jobs with a time interval like first one at 09.00 second one at 09.05, third one at 09.10 and forth one at 09.15 and see if that fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your job cannot use the Desktop environment.

Check your agent service settings:
Log on As:

> User account under which Control‑M Agent service will run.
>
> Valid values:
>
> ```
> Local System Account – Service logs on as the system account.
> Allow Service to Interact with Desktop – This option is valid only if the service is running as a local system account.
> ```
>
> Selected – the service provides a user interface on a desktop that can
>   be used by whoever is logged in when the service is started. Default.
>
> Unselected – the service does not provide a user interface.
>
> ```
> This Account – User account under which Control‑M Agent service will run.
>
> NOTE: If the owner of any Control-M/Server jobs has a "roaming profile" or if job output (OUTPUT) will be copied to or from other computers, the Log in mode must be set to This Account.
> ```
>
> Default: Local System Account